# node.js variable inside HTML a href attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a variable of `labels` which is an array in Node.js. And I want to place the first item in the list within a href attribute of HTML. I tried `<a href="https://chiniki.ng/s/?q={labels[0]}">Link</a>`. The item is not coming through. How do I make the q=val take the item?. Any help please?

Comment: You need to provide more context, to allow us to help. What framework or lib do you use to solve the problem, what have you tried so far and why it's not working?

Comment: You need use $  test this ``<a href="https://chiniki.ng/s/?q=${labels[0]}">Link</a>``

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the contribution. I finally solved it by concatenating the link with the variable, stored it in another variable and then placed the new variable next to the href attribute without any quotaions.

```
let dlink = 'https://chiniki.ng/s/?q='+labels[0];
```

then

```
<a href={dlink}>Link</a>
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

use rendering lib like the famous `ejs` then pass labels array to the frontend view in the same line when you render the html page. ie.

```
res.render('YOUR_HTML_FILE', {labels: YOUR_ARRAY_VARIABLE });
```

Answer (score 0):

- The href attribute value would have to be in `{}`
- You can use ES6 template strings. The incl. variable or function needs to be in `` ` `` (backticks)
- and I used url encoding here to be sure that the incl. value is properly url-escaped (e.g. `@` -> `%40`)

```
<a href={`https://chiniki.ng/s/?q=${encodeURIComponent(labels[0])}`}>Link</a>
```